# How do I call or use a 64-bit Shared Library(.SO) file in Linux?

Tags: linker, debian, 64-bit, shared-libraries

I'm relatively new to Linux and am having trouble trying to figure out the intricacies of .SO files and how (64-bit) shared libraries(and their versions, dependencies etc) work; and how to link them and use them in a basic C++ program??

The scenario is this: I have a shared library file(single physical file) called libfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit. I have installed Debian(latest version) 64-bit on VMWare. I have installed (I believe) all the basic C++ development tools use apt-get.

Now I wish to write a simple program in C++ that will LINK libfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit, and enable me to call two specific functions "exported" by this .so file. Unfortunately, the environment/system set up on my machine is preventing me from linking to this library successfully.

Can anyone guide me on this please?

I have included below, some pertinent details regarding the .SO file it self. The function I wish to use(from the .SO file) has the following function-prototype(and should work):

```
int32_t DEF_EXPORT TZ_FAID_Size(int64_t start_time,
int32_t roster_count,
int64_t * roster_from,
int64_t * roster_to,
int32_t * roster_ids,
int32_t & id_cnt);
```

I'm from a Windows background (Dynamic linking and DLLs-wise) and am struggling to get this .SO file liked and used in a basic C++ test program.

```
root@debian:/home/maitreya/lib# ldd libfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit 

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff667ff000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f3300a6f000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f33007ed000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3300461000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f330024b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3300f93000)
```

---

```
root@debian:/home/maitreya/lib# nm libfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit 

0000000000208c70 d DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
0000000000006ebb T TZ_FAID_Process
0000000000006e04 T TZ_FAID_Size
0000000000007447 T TZ_FAID_Version
0000000000208028 a _DYNAMIC
0000000000208230 a _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000000011ca T _Z15FetchExpiryDatePiS_S_
```

and so on..

Comment: "Unfortunately, the environment/system set up on my machine is preventing me from linking to this library successfully." - What is your command line? What error do you get?

Comment: I've tried many(managed to link it it once, but the resulting binary didn't execute.) At present, i have the .SO sitting in the same folder as my sample prrogram, and I'm using :  g++ useFAID.cc -L.  -lfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit -o test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit.  I've tried running ldconfig and update environment variables etc. Also tried updating the GLIBC library(32-bit) flavour. The current error I get is: " /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfaidtz.so.3.0.0_debian6_64bit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status "

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve this one with the help of a few folks. Thanks to everyone. The steps I took were:  1) Put the actual Shared Library file(.SO) in the /usr/lib folder.  2) Create a SOFT link to it in the same folder.    3) run ldconfig -v(to update the library cache)  4) rebuild my C++ program in my own folder.  5) It ran and completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at some of the standard libraries installed on your system you will see that they are soft linked. For example: I have /lib/libgpm.so.2.1.0 with a soft link /lib/libgpm.so.

Try creating a soft link libfaidtz.so to your library and then link with `-lfaidtz`.

Comment: Thank you for that ! Finally managed to get it to link! Now I'm getting an execution error(Sorry, am not from a Linux background):     root@debian:/home/maitreya/UseFAID# ./test
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libfaidtz.so.3.0.0_template: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok then your system can find the shared object at build time but not run time. You could try adding the directory where your library is to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Run the following command and try to your program again `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/your/so`

Comment: PLease see above. I have managed to finally get this library to talk to my program. Thanks to you and a few others, and the internet. The key was to put the library in a system-wid-e LIB directory, then create a symbolic link, THEN do a LDCONFIG -v to update the library cache and ... then only build my program. Yay! Thanks to everyone! I would like to to leave these steps as a compelte answer to my  quesiton, but I think answering your own question is illegal o this site, so i won't do that. THANK YOU.

Comment: Great stuff. Glad to be of help. And a very nice summary of the steps all in one place as well. Good thinking.